# puzzled by vs puzzled at - nuance, transitivity?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"This puzzled me."

Which is equivalent -

> I was puzzled by this.
>
> I was puzzled at this.

Comment: Without context they are both valid.

Comment: And completely equivalent?

Comment: No. `I was puzzled by this` == My puzzlement was caused by this. `I was puzzled at this` == My puzzlement was directed towards this. Your first choice matches your original sentence more closely.

Comment: I was puzzled by his statement, so I puzzled at it for some time. (Passive and active forms take different prepositions.)

Comment: Also, I was puzzled by the cryptic message on the door.  I was puzzled at his sudden outburst.

Comment: Is this question a better fit for ELL?